# tic-tac-toe programming python errors

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

errors "indent expected","unresolved reference 'moves'","call to *init* super class is missed","parameter 'moves' value is not used"

```
class PlayerX(Player):
    """ Player X's moves"""
    def __init__(self, moves):
    self.moves = moves


    def xmove(self):
        print("Move Player X")
        move = int(input())
        if -1 < move < 9:
            for i in self.moves[move]:
                if i == ' ':
                    super(PlayerX, self).makeMove(move, "X")
                    print(self.moves)
                    return 1
            else:
                print("That's not a valid move")
                return 0
```

Comment: hello i am getting error in first line  "def_init_(self, moves):  self.moves= moves " these were supposed to be a part of code dont know why they became text after i posted errors are mentioned in question please help me i need to submit it by tonight.

Comment: Update your question with the informTion from your comment, so that it ist all together.

Answer (score 0):

This would seem to be a typo.  If `self.moves = moves` is supposed to be in the body of `__init__`, shouldn't it be indented like

```
def __init__(self, moves):
    self.moves = moves
```

Comment: Yes that was the part of the code and when i run the file it is showing those errors that i have mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the "else" of your "if" needs to be indented. But that could also be due to the cut-and-paste in StackOverflow.

As a suggestion, use gist.github.com to post your code snippet. Once you have a GitHub login, it is a very simple way put up some Python code. It will be indented and highlighted properly and also makes it easier for people to help you.

Finally, you probably don't need `super(PlayerX, self).makeMove` as you subclass from `Player`. You can just say `self.makeMove`.